# What would I call the author and date line in a blog?

Tags: titles

What can I call the second line in a blog post heading such as below? I tend to call this the author and date line, but is there a single term that encapsulates this identity?

> ### Blog Post Title
>
> *Written by Some Person | 14 July 2015*                    <-- what's this line called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the **byline,** following newspaper practice.

> A line in a newspaper naming the writer of an article:
>   *his byline appeared in the first issue*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/byline)

Comment: I had no idea, that a line carrying the author's name and the date had a name.

Comment: *Byline;* line showing who it's by. *Dateline:* line showing date of writing. Many newspapers had both, especially when writing from far-flung places without telegraphy. News of Hillary conquering Everest took two or three days to reach London in 1953.

Comment: So, you think byline is more appropriate to encapsulate both? BTW, I appreciate you distinguishing between the two. @AndrewLeach

Comment: I would only use *dateline* for a date. I've never heard of anything but *byline* where the line includes the author (no matter what else is included).

Comment: @ThisClark There is no satisfying single word which captures all the meta-data of an article or post. I once [looked really hard](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/188585/55623) for one.

Answer (score 0):

The term I have seen is **header**, but I have only ever run into this issue with Word documents.